# Is there any point to using Queue in this Ruby threaded example instead of an Array?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, queue

From the following threaded example in ruby docs, it looks like [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) isn't doing anything more different than an Array...so when would I use Queue over Array in threaded Ruby code?

```
require 'thread'

queue = Queue.new

producer = Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    sleep rand(i) # simulate expense
    queue << i
    puts "#{i} produced"
  end
end

consumer = Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    value = queue.pop
    sleep rand(i/2) # simulate expense
    puts "consumed #{value}"
  end
end

consumer.join
```

Comment: they're functionally the same. you can implement a stack or a queue with an array, but a queue is a uni-directional datastore. just depends on the situation, one may be clearer than the other.

in this case, the consumer seems to want the data in FIFO, so pushing & popping is useful.

Answer (score 4):

[`Queue#pop`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html#method-i-pop) will suspend the calling thread if the queue is empty until data is pushed.

If you used regular array, there is a chance that some of the `pop`s will consume actual data, and some of them will just get `nil` if there is a point at which more *consumer* tasks ran than *producer* ones.